# Leer xml obtenido por nusoap en php

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Estoy aprendiendo a realizar webservice con `SOAP` y para ello he utilizado la libreria `nusoap`.

Todo esta correcto, el unico problema es que no se como tratar el xml una vez lo obtengo, pues tien un formato como este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:Service.getViajesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org">
                <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="unnamed_struct_use_soapval[9]">
                    <item>
                        <title>Titulo</title>
                        <img>Imagen</img>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <title>Titulo</title>
                        <img>Imagen</img>
                    </item>
```

El código que tengo en el cliente para leerlo es:

```
private function _soapResponse($result)
{
     $xmlResponse = $this->_soapClient->responseData;
     print_r($xmlResponse);
}
```

El `print_r()` muestra el xml que he indicado arriba.

Como puedo leerlo para guardarlo en un `array`???

Comment: Creo que conviene agregar un poco más del XML de respuesta, incluyendo la parte donde efectivamente están los datos, para poder usar esa estructura al responder.

Comment: He modificado mi pegunta @Mariano

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una segunda opción, si el *Web Service* te devuelve un *XML*, puedes convertirlo a *JSON* si se te hace más fácil controlar la información.

Por ejemplo:

1. Función para convertir *XML* a *JSON*.

```
function xmlToJson(xml) 
{
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) {
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

2. Convertir *XML* a *JSON*.

```
var json = xmlToJson(xml)
```

3. Conversión y acceso a *JSON*.

```
var json = xmlToJson(xml)
var data = json.ArrayOfG_barras.g_barras;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var id = parseInt(data[i].Valor["#text"]);
    var name = data[i].Nombre["#text"];
}
```

Con eso ya puedes controlar la información en formato *JSON*. Como aclaración, el valor `json.ArrayOfG_barras.g_barras;` lo puse así para acceder más rápido al nodo, por que al convertir el *XML* a *JSON*, ya traía esa información, la respuesta de mi servicio web (*ASMX*). Puedes verificar tus nodos desde la consola de cualquier navegador imprimiendo en consola el valor de la variable *JSON* (`console.log(json);`).

Answer (score 0):

Usando [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-string.php) y [JSON](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.json.php) puedes lograrlo, por ejemplo:

```
private function _soapResponse($result)
{
    $xmlResponse = $this->_soapClient->responseData;
    $array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse)),true);
    print_r($array);
}
```

Respuesta original [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php/20431742#comment32312737_20431742).